# Pre-render hook in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, hook, prerender

There is something like pre-render hook in symfony 1.4? I want to execute some code right before view render starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set a filter before the view is rendered in the `<app>/config/filters.yml` file. For further details, take a look [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `preExecute()` in action class: http://www.symfony-blog.co.uk/tag/preexecute/.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony allows you to [configure the view class used](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_module_configuration) at the module level (module.yml):

```
all:                  # For all environments
  view_class:         myPHP
```

You could then create a myPHPView class and override the `sfPHPView::render` method.